# How to add .00 in FloatField of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I did this in my models.py

```
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    discounted_price = models.FloatField()
```

& my prices are looking like 14,999.0 but i want it to look like 14,999.00

So how can i add that extra zero after decimal ?

Comment: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-a-floatfield-for-money.html

Comment: Great link. Good info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DecimalField for your Prices.
From Django Docs:

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField.decimal_places